# How can I disable a windows's resize action in X window system?

Tags: xlib, window-managers, xserver, x11

I am trying to use xprop to set a window's allowed actions,for example,I want to make a resizeable window become unresizeable by the following command.

```
xprop -id "0x04400015" -format _NET_WM_ALLOWED_ACTIONS 32a -set _NET_WM_ALLOWED_ACTIONS " _NET_WM_ACTION_FULLSCREEN, _NET_WM_ACTION_MINIMIZE, _NET_WM_ACTION_SHADE, _NET_WM_ACTION_MAXIMIZE_HORZ, _NET_WM_ACTION_MAXIMIZE_VERT, _NET_WM_ACTION_CHANGE_DESKTOP, _NET_WM_ACTION_ABOVE, _NET_WM_ACTION_BELOW"
```

I remove the action "_NET_WM_ACTION_RESIZE" in _NET_WM_ALLOWED_ACTIONS ,But the window can still be resized.

Is there anything wrong? And are there any other ways to make it?

Comment: I guess WM (which one you are using?) reads this property at the moment window is created and reparented. You need to reparent child window manually again

Comment: I use KWM.Could you give more detials about reparenting a windows?

Comment: maybe restarting KVM with kill -HUP afterwards would help